# I'm gettting ValueError for a kmeans python module imported from sklearn

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn

I ported an old pytorch code from github repo. I am supposed to run a kmeans.py file for kmeans. When I do, I get

```
valueerror:too many values to unpack.
```

Here's the kmeans code.

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-


from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from retrieval import load_feat_db
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from config import DATASET_BASE, N_CLUSTERS
import os


if __name__ == '__main__':
    feats, labels = load_feat_db()
    #model = KMeans(n_clusters=N_CLUSTERS, random_state=0, n_jobs=-1).fit(feats)
    model = KMeans(n_clusters=N_CLUSTERS, random_state=1, n_jobs=1).fit(feats)
    model_path = os.path.join(DATASET_BASE, r'models', r'kmeans.m')
    joblib.dump(model, model_path)
```

and here's the load_feat_db() that i think is giving error.

```
@timer_with_task("Loading feature database")
def load_feat_db():
    feat_all = os.path.join(DATASET_BASE, 'all_feat.npy')
    feat_list = os.path.join(DATASET_BASE, 'all_feat.list')
    color_feat = os.path.join(DATASET_BASE, 'all_color_feat.npy')
    if not os.path.isfile(feat_list) or not os.path.isfile(feat_all) or not os.path.isfile(color_feat):
        print("No feature db file! Please run feature_extractor.py first.")
        return
    deep_feats = np.load(feat_all)
    color_feats = np.load(color_feat)
    with open(feat_list) as f:
        labels = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), f.readlines()))
    return deep_feats, color_feats, labels
```

I read scikit documentation, the syntax is correct, i tried changing the random_state seed and n_jobs = 1 (for single core trial run) but the issues persists. The lambda function seems okay. Is it really not working because of sci kit? I'm now planning on using other kmeans like the one in opencv package.

Comment: Where *exactly* in the code does the error pop up? Please post the full error trace (not in the comments, edit & update your post accordingly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `load_feat_db()` returns 3 values, `return deep_feats, color_feats, labels`

Yet when you call it you only allocate space for 2 return values, `feats, labels = load_feat_db()`

Try using the following function call instead, `d_feats, c_feats, labels = load_feat_db()`

Comment: @Sunny can you click the "Accept answer" tick mark to show other people who have the same problem that this worked please